# Bypassing the WHERE clause when the filter parameter comes as null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure and need to bypass the WHERE clause where input as null.

Please find the below condition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPERSON_SELECT]    
(
@PersonID INT = NULL,
@OrganizationID INT = NULL,
@ManagerID INT = NULL 
)
AS

BEGIN
SELECT PERSON.name, ORGANIZATION.name,PERSON.manager 
FROM PERSON 
    INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION 
        ON PERSON.person_id = ORGANIZATION.person_id    
WHERE PERSON.person_id = @PersonID  
    and ORGANIZATION.organization_id = @OrganizationID  
    and PERSON.manager_id = @ManagerID 

END
GO
```

Iam facing an issue while the input as null, at that case need to avoid where condition.

Example:

If @PersonID is null then my select query needs the following structure:

```
SELECT PERSON.name, ORGANIZATION.name,PERSON.manager 
FROM PERSON 
    INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION 
        ON PERSON.person_id = ORGANIZATION.person_id    
WHERE ORGANIZATION.organization_id = @OrganizationID
    and PERSON.manager_id = @ManagerID
```

I would like to avoid dynamic queries.

Answer (score 5):

Bracket each parameter and test for null i.e.

```
(PERSON.manager_id=@ManagerID or @ManagerID is NUll)
```

Comment: I like this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PERSON.name, ORGANIZATION.name, PERSON.manager 
FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION ON PERSON.person_id=ORGANIZATION.person_id
WHERE 
(@PersonID is null or PERSON.person_id=@PersonID) 
and (@OrganizationID is null or ORGANIZATION.organization_id=@OrganizationID)
and (@ManagerID is null or PERSON.manager_id=@ManagerID)
```

Comment: Should point out that you can increase performance in SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and SQL 2008 R2 CU1 (10.50.1702) and later using OPTION (RECOMPILE) in your procedure.  As it sits the optimizer will likely not use a selective index.  You can get into more trouble from parameter sniffing too. Here is a LONG but excellent [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#SPandCUs).  Look under the heading STATIC SQL.  If you are using an ealier version there is some guidance [here] (http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) under STATIC SQL.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favourite method is:

`WHERE PERSON.manager_id = COALESCE(@ManagerID, PERSON.manager_id)`

Using a [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) for each parameter looks nicer.

This will match even if `@ManagerID IS NULL` as it always matches itself, `PERSON.manager_id`, but stops if `@ManagerID IS NOT NULL`.

It's worth noting that you can give `COALESCE(expression1, expression2, n)` as many parameters as you want.

Comment: Note that this method can cause table scans, which may lead to performance issues on large tables.  It's expedient, but expensive.

Comment: Agree with @Stuart.  Coalesce and IsNull are bad news.  See Jeff Smith's blog post[link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx)